# Why does the monitor lose signal when I turn off/on my monitor on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, motherboard, signal

Ever since I installed Windows 7 on my machine, my monitor has been acting strangely.

When I boot my machine, my monitor starts up and receives signals fine.

However, no matter what if I decide to turn off my monitor I simply can't turn it back on again.

It keeps saying No Signal. I clicked on all buttons on the keyboards and clicked my mouse to death repeatedly trying to get the monitor to wake up, but it won't.

The only way for me to get my monitor signal is to reboot my machine.

This is the spec on my machine.

- BIOSTAR Hi-Fi A85S3 FM2 AMD A85X (Hudson D4) HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX AMD Motherboard
- Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL
- AMD A10-5800K Trinity Quad-Core 3.8 GHz Socket FM2 100W AD580KWOHJBOX Desktop APU (CPU + GPU) with DirectX 11 Graphic AMD Radeon HD 7660D
- GT 9800 video card
- EVGA 500 W1 80+, 500W Continuous Power, 3 Year Warranty Power Supply 100-W1-0500-KR

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What do you see when you bring up the Windows 7 display settings?  Does it show the 2nd monitor connected?  Is there a "detect" button?

Comment: Maybe input source on the monitor itself is wrong after turning it on and it does not autodetect? If it helps, try pulling the cable to see if that helps.

Comment: What connector are you using on your screen?

Answer (score -1):

I have run into a similar situation on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 now. The issue was on two separate machines with no matching hardware. They both are running AMD video cards.

The reason I am responding here is the latest one, running Windows 8.1, is using the exact same AMD GPU. The only solution I ran into running windows 7 was to use Eyefinity through the Catalyst Control Centre.

If I had all three of my monitors configured as one monitor I did not have this issue any more. When using the monitors separately, I had this issue constantly. I ended up upgrading the windows 7 computer to Windows 10 using the latest drivers I no longer have this issue running the monitors with or without Eyefinity.

As for the Windows 8.1 computer, I am still having this issue when running monitors as separate desktops. I understand that your setup has a Nvidia graphics card so this may not just be an AMD issue like I thought but rather an OS issue. If I run into a solution with the Windows 8.1 machine I will add it here as well for future use.

Comment: While interesting, your answer does not address the issues the OP has.